# c++ forward declaration for a non-class typedef

Tags: c++, typedef, forward-declaration

I have this:

```
//forward declaration of Foo <-- this is my question
void doSome(Foo foo);

typedef void* Foo; //Foo is defined later as void*

void doSome(Foo foo)
{
   //code here..
}
```

How can I forward declare Foo in a way compatible with void*?

This is an oversimplified example, of course is trivial here, but the idea is having multiple implementations, like this:

```
//forward declaration of Foo <-- this is my question
void doSome(Foo foo);

//[implementation1_internal.h]
typedef void* Foo; //Foo is defined later as void*

void doSome(Foo foo)
{
   //code here..
}

//[implementation2_internal.h]
typedef int* Foo; //Foo is defined later as int*

void doSome(Foo foo)
{
   //code here..
}
```

and select one of them using preprocessor directives. (This is irrelevant, just to show  the example is not just silly).

Comment: Why can't you put the typedef beforehand?

Comment: It's trivially possible (or move the forward declaration down, same thing). You can't actually call `doSome(Foo)` anyway, before `Foo` is defined.

Comment: this is just an example. I will have multiple declarations for Foo and doSome in more than one header file

Comment: "*This is irrelevant, just to show the example is not just silly*" Actually, I'd say the example is extremely silly -- why do you want to subvert the type system like this? If the functions should be able to take different pointer types, then make them function templates...

Answer (score 1):

Why cannot you put typedef before. If you declare function having an argument of given custom type (be it class or typedef) you need to somehow declare this class as well.

As in case of pointers to class/struct, the size is perfectly well known even if the class member are not known (=sizeof(pointer)), in case of typedef'ed types, the size cannot be known unless you provide your the full typedef declaration.

Therefore, the solution is to place `typedef` before your function declaration.

You should have:

```
 // declarations
 typedef void* Foo; //Foo is defined later as void*
 void doSome(Foo foo);

 // definitions
 void doSome(Foo foo)
 {
    //code here..
 }
```

If you cannot modify the definitions due to some reason, you can repeat typedef twice (as long as both are non-conflicting / exactly the same):

```
 // declarations
 typedef void* Foo; 
 void doSome(Foo foo);

 // definitions
 typedef void* Foo; 
 void doSome(Foo foo)
 {
    //code here..
 }
```

---

**EDIT after question edit**

The best way would be to have overloaded functions:

```
  void doSome(void* foo)
  {
      // void* version
  }

  void doSome(int* foo)
  {
      // int* version
  }
```

It is not a good idea to have different `Foo`s around your project.

Comment: Thanks Krizz, if you want, see my edition and maybe will clarify what i need.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef void* Foo;

void doSome(Foo foo);

void doSome(Foo foo)
{
   //code here..
}
```

You only need to forward-declare classes which have implementations. Typedefs don't have implementations.